# How to stop animation with jQuery timers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how to stop an animation made with jQuery timers. I think I have tried everything, I would really like your help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta content='yes' name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable'>
        <meta content='default' name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style'>
        <meta content='width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>
        <title>HeartMath - Danmark</title>
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script src='inc/jquery.timers-1.1.2.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" > 

    jQuery.fn.log = function (msg) {
      console.log("%s: %o", msg, this);
      return this;
    };   var fixgeometry = function() {
        /* Some orientation changes leave the scroll position at something
         * that isn't 0,0. This is annoying for user experience. */
        scroll(0, 0);

        /* Calculate the geometry that our content area should take */
        var header = $(".header:visible");
        var footer = $(".footer:visible");
        var content = $(".content:visible");
        var viewport_height = $(window).height();

        var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight();;

        /* Trim margin/border/padding height */
        content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
        content.height(content_height);
      }; /* fixgeometry */

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).bind("orientationchange resize pageshow", fixgeometry);


             var animationSpeed = 3500;
             var animationHeight = $(window).height() * 0.70;
                $("input[type='radio']").bind( "change", function(event, ui) {


                if($(this).val() == "true") {
                    startAnimation(animationSpeed);
                    $(this).log("animationen burde starte");

                } 
                else  {
                    stopAnimation();
                    $(this).log("animationen burde stopppe");
                } 

                }).log("der blev trykket"); 




                function startAnimation(animationDuration) {
                    $(".breather").everyTime(10, function(){                         
                    $(".breather").animate({top:animationHeight}, animationDuration).animate({top:"0"}, animationDuration);
                    }).log("startAnimation");
                };
                function stopAnimation() {
                    $(".breather").stopTime().stop().log("stopAnimation");

                };



    });
    </script>
        <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        width: 100%;
    }
    div.breather {
        display: block;
        position:relative;
    }
    }
    </style>
        <link href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-mobile/hm-mobile-theme.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        <div data-role='page' data-theme='a'>
          <div class='header' id="header" data-role='header'> <img src="img/hm-logo.png" style="margin:0px auto;" height="40" /> </div>
          <div class='content' data-role='content'>
            <div class="breather">landscape!</div>
          </div>
          <div class='footer' data-role='footer'>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
              <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <input type="radio" name="ignition" id="start" value="true" />
                <label for="start">Start</label>
                <input type="radio" name="ignition" id="stop" value="false" checked="checked" />
                <label for="stop">Stop</label>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What happens now is that when i press stop.. the animation just reverses and loops again

Comment: Do you want to post your html or at least a sanatized snippet?

Comment: Here you are. i've also added the console log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call .stop() to stop the jQuery animation, change it to .stop(true) to clear the animation queue (docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)). I'm not sure why there is a queue, but it looks like it has something to do with the timers plugin that you are using. Use queue().length to see how many animations are left in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the stopAnimation is being called by adding some debugging (console.log()). You call stopAnimation without an argument, but the function has an argument, that's not used.

So add some debugging to stopanimation and the if(val==false) statement. If that all works as expected we can continue the search.

Comment: i've also edited to code above.. so it shoes all of the markup